# Refrigerator Compressor not working?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, thermostat-c-wire, 240v, relay

I unplugged then plugged back in my fridge an it isn't cooling or freezing! Does that mean my compressor is  no more working? The light comes on inside the icebox?? Just not cooling or freezing..

Comment: Means something is not working.  Could be a few things including the compressor, broken wire, bad sensor.

Comment: Unplug for 15 minutes. Plug it back in and listen carefully, you will hear a hum then shortly a click and the humming will stop. This may keep cycling. That is a sign the compressor is not working. If nothing it could be an open winding in the compressor or more and likely a bad thermostat or safety device.

Comment: Did you unplug it to move it? Was it tipped when it moved?